# SSIS How to run .net core Action with Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs

Hi everyone  I'm new about JOBS I know just what is it and how it works.

I gotta create job to run everyday. This is easy part It can managed from SSIS but the job (accually there will be a lot more job) gotta run .netcore function.

Just be like it will occur everyday 9 am and run controller function like "home/sendMessageToUsers".

This part i couldn't figured out. Every example i saw in youtube or else works with sql querys.

I know it may a bit silly question but i just can't made it. Thank you

Comment: Is your question "how do you invoke a web request from SQL Agent Jobs"?

Comment: No can i run Recurring Jobs without hangfire

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks